# How do I create radio inputs from data from the database as apposed to handwritten forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am learning rails and am building a mini poll app as a learning tool. I know how I can create forms by hand but when I want to build radio buttons for a form I am confused as to how to do this: The code that renders my polls choices are as follows:

```
def show
  @poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
end

# show.html.erb - this is where I want to render the radio buttons/form
<h2><%= @poll.question %></h2>
<ul id="choices">
  <% @poll.choices.each do |choice| %>
    <li>
      <%= choice.choice %> &rarr; 
     </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

My models are pretty straight forward:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :choices, :dependent => :delete_all
  validates :question, :presence => true
end

class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  validates :choice, :presence => true
end
```

My question is how do I build a form with radio buttons based on the above? Basically I want my votes column to increment by 1 when this form is submitted, I can handle that but my confusion is how to build this form, can anyone help me?

Thanks

- Jeff

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing your model code. Tip: read up on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thanks Thilo, I updated my question with more information. Reading those docs now as well.

Comment: Use simple_form - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out-of-the-box rails form helpers, something like this should work (not tested):

```
<%= form_for(@poll) do |f| %>
  <% @poll.choices.each do |choice| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :chosen_id, choice.id %> <%= choice.choice %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the `update` method of your `PollsController`, do your model update based on the value of `params[:chosen_id]`.

This is not the most elegant way to do this, but lacking more information about your models, it should be enough to get you started. This is pretty basic Rails stuff, by the way. I suggest you read up on [Rails form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for the basics, then maybe take a look at [nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) (which my example is not), and maybe use some of the great gems that simplify form handling such as [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), as Michael Durrant suggested in the comment.

Comment: Im sorry thilo, i forgot to mark this is answered, thanks for your response!